# firebase + audio_service: application stuck on splash after push notification when app is terminated

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, audio-service

### Short issue description

After added `audio_service`, my application is stuck on splash screen after closed from background and push notification (firebase) is received.

### In details

1. My application is using the following plugins:
   `firebase_messaging` (version 11.1.0): For supporting FCM (push notifications)
   `audio_service` (version 0.18.1): For support for playing audio in background with player in notification area.
2. Before adding `audio_service` to my application, there was no issue opening the application after receiving a push notification while application was closed.

#### How to reproduce

1. Close the application, also from background.
2. Send a firebase cloud message, so the application is started in the background.
3. Start the application by clicking its icon.
4. Application is stuck on splash screen.

#### Relevant information

As part of the `audio_service` plugin installation, the `activity` name was changed to `com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity`.

Here is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.twtech.twelveqa">
    
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:name=".Application" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="TokCast QA" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/tw_backup_rules" tools:replace="android:fullBackupContent" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round">
        <activity
          android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask" 
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" 
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Add this filter, if you want to support sharing text into your app-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Add this filter, if you want to support sharing images into your app-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Add this filter, if you want to support sharing videos into your app-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Add this filter, if you want to support sharing any type of files-->
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
             </intent-filter>

        <!-- URI Scheme for verified deep links -->
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with https://YOUR_HOST -->
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="qa.12.live" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- URI Scheme for deep links -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with tokcastqa:// -->
            <data android:scheme="tokcastqa" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
        
        <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
   
</manifest>
```

Logs when application starts in background

```
2021-11-16 09:12:53.331 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/ApplicationLoaders: Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
2021-11-16 09:12:53.384 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-11-16 09:12:53.385 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-11-16 09:12:53.413 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2021-11-16 09:12:53.452 17561-17589/com.twtech.twelveqa I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
2021-11-16 09:08:57.999 2435-2435/? D/OpSWarpChargingView: level is same as latest one [100]
2021-11-16 09:12:53.235 17561-17561/? I/libc: SetHeapTaggingLevel: tag level set to 0
2021-11-16 09:12:53.242 17561-17561/? I/twtech.twelveq: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-11-16 09:12:53.255 17561-17561/? I/twtech.twelveq: Unquickening 21 vdex files!
2021-11-16 09:12:53.255 17561-17561/? E/twtech.twelveq: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x800000
2021-11-16 09:12:53.235 17561-17561/? I/libc: SetHeapTaggingLevel: tag level set to 0
2021-11-16 09:12:53.242 17561-17561/? I/twtech.twelveq: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-11-16 09:12:53.255 17561-17561/? I/twtech.twelveq: Unquickening 21 vdex files!
2021-11-16 09:12:53.255 17561-17561/? E/twtech.twelveq: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x800000
2021-11-16 09:12:53.235 17561-17561/? I/libc: SetHeapTaggingLevel: tag level set to 0
2021-11-16 09:12:53.242 17561-17561/? I/twtech.twelveq: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-11-16 09:12:53.255 17561-17561/? I/twtech.twelveq: Unquickening 21 vdex files!
2021-11-16 09:12:53.255 17561-17561/? E/twtech.twelveq: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x800000
2021-11-16 09:12:53.475 17561-17595/com.twtech.twelveqa E/sqlite3_android: ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2021-11-16 09:12:53.493 17561-17600/com.twtech.twelveqa W/PlatformVersion: Build version must be at least 5954562 to support R in gmscore
2021-11-16 09:12:53.493 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 5431 ).
2021-11-16 09:12:53.497 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-11-16 09:12:53.498 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/FLTFireContextHolder: received application context.
2021-11-16 09:12:53.501 17561-17604/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2021-11-16 09:12:53.517 17561-17593/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 46000
2021-11-16 09:12:53.517 17561-17593/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2021-11-16 09:12:53.517 17561-17593/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.twtech.twelveqa
2021-11-16 09:12:53.522 17561-17609/com.twtech.twelveqa I/ResourceExtractor: Found extracted resources res_timestamp-4297-1637046535931
2021-11-16 09:12:53.525 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/FLTFireMsgReceiver: broadcast received for message
2021-11-16 09:12:53.555 17561-17593/com.twtech.twelveqa E/sqlite3_android: ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2021-11-16 09:12:53.558 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/FlutterJNI: FlutterJNI.setRefreshRateFPS called more than once
2021-11-16 09:12:53.562 17561-17609/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FLTFireMsgService: Service has not yet started, messages will be queued.
2021-11-16 09:12:53.569 17561-17615/com.twtech.twelveqa W/FlutterJNI: FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
2021-11-16 09:12:53.581 17561-17617/com.twtech.twelveqa I/ResourceExtractor: Found extracted resources res_timestamp-4297-1637046535931
2021-11-16 09:12:53.584 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FLTFireBGExecutor: Creating background FlutterEngine instance.
2021-11-16 09:12:53.597 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/FlutterJNI: FlutterJNI.init called more than once
2021-11-16 09:12:53.606 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/twtech.twelveqa: type=1400 audit(0.0:17734): avc: denied { read } for name="max_map_count" dev="proc" ino=22216952 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_29:s0:c151,c259,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_max_map_count:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 app=com.twtech.twelveqa
2021-11-16 09:12:53.623 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 3571974a10, I64bd74b5bd
    Build Date                       : 09/11/20
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.9.12.10.00.00.582.274
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-11-16 09:12:53.624 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : S P 10.0.5 AArch64
2021-11-16 09:12:53.624 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2021-11-16 09:12:53.630 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016dd091, ME: 0x00000000
2021-11-16 09:12:53.657 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/MediaBrowserCompat: Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2021-11-16 09:12:53.665 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.twtech.twelveqa
2021-11-16 09:12:53.668 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/DeviceInfoPlugin: Don't use TaskQueues.
2021-11-16 09:12:53.669 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/ffmpeg-kit-flutter: FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin created com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.flutter.FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin@21f9ae6.
2021-11-16 09:12:53.712 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 95.0.4638.74 (code 463807434)
2021-11-16 09:12:53.759 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/twtech.twelveq: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-11-16 09:12:53.759 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/twtech.twelveq: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-11-16 09:12:53.759 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/twtech.twelveq: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-11-16 09:12:53.759 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/twtech.twelveq: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-11-16 09:12:53.759 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/twtech.twelveq: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-11-16 09:12:53.765 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/cr_WVCFactoryProvider: Loaded version=95.0.4638.74 minSdkVersion=29 isBundle=true multiprocess=true packageId=2
2021-11-16 09:12:53.787 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/cr_LibraryLoader: Successfully loaded native library
2021-11-16 09:12:53.788 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder: Flushed 7 samples from 7 histograms.
2021-11-16 09:12:53.901 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa E/chromium: [ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(179)] Failed to grant sandbox access to network context data for /data/user/0/com.twtech.twelveqa/app_webview/Default with result 7: No such file or directory (2)
2021-11-16 09:12:53.924 17561-17640/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:38229/nINHYI44rX4=/
2021-11-16 09:12:53.934 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/PathProviderPlugin: Don't use TaskQueues.
2021-11-16 09:12:54.022 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/DeviceInfoPlugin: Don't use TaskQueues.
2021-11-16 09:12:54.023 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/ffmpeg-kit-flutter: FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin created com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.flutter.FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin@97be326.
2021-11-16 09:12:54.028 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa D/PathProviderPlugin: Don't use TaskQueues.
2021-11-16 09:12:54.031 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/System.out: flutterEngine warmed up
2021-11-16 09:12:54.051 17561-17593/com.twtech.twelveqa E/sqlite3_android: ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2021-11-16 09:12:54.063 17561-17593/com.twtech.twelveqa E/sqlite3_android: ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2021-11-16 09:12:55.688 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FLTFireMsgService: FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!
2021-11-16 09:12:55.757 17561-17623/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: backgroundMessageHandler: message
2021-11-16 09:12:56.158 17561-17561/com.twtech.twelveqa W/FLTFireMsgService: Attempted to start a duplicate background isolate. Returning...
2021-11-16 09:12:56.367 17561-17717/com.twtech.twelveqa E/sqlite3_android: ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2021-11-16 09:12:56.513 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.510116Z General, I: GlobalConfigurationModel: getGlobalConfigurationParam, GlobalConfiguration is null
2021-11-16 09:12:56.514 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.514643Z General, I: GlobalConfigurationModel: getGlobalConfigurationParam, GlobalConfiguration is null
2021-11-16 09:12:56.515 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.514934Z General, I: GlobalConfigurationModel: getGlobalConfigurationParam, GlobalConfiguration is null
2021-11-16 09:12:56.520 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.520617Z General, D: AuthService: Awake...
2021-11-16 09:12:56.528 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.527972Z General, D: AuthService: init
2021-11-16 09:12:56.557 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.557173Z General, D: ModelsManager init
2021-11-16 09:12:56.573 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.572870Z General, I: GlobalConfigurationModel: getGlobalConfigurationParam, GlobalConfiguration is null
2021-11-16 09:12:56.573 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.573653Z AudioSequencer, I: AudioPlayerTask: Timeout is 1000 msec
2021-11-16 09:12:56.771 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:56.653474Z General, I: Clock skew is -118 milliseconds
2021-11-16 09:12:56.843 17561-17728/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app Twelve
2021-11-16 09:12:56.854 17561-17604/com.twtech.twelveqa I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2021-11-16 09:12:56.999 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:userInfoTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.006 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:configTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.012 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:groupInfoTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.014 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:memberPermissionOverrideTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.020 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:groupMemberInfoTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.026 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:userDetailsTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.033 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:feedTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.035 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:globalConfigurationTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.036 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:reactionsTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.038 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:settingsTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.039 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:pendingTransfersTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.040 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:groupTopicTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.043 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: init() -> tableName:resourcesTable
2021-11-16 09:12:57.120 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.002629Z General, I: Keyboard languages: he-IL,en-US,ja-JP,zh-Hans-CN,en-IL
2021-11-16 09:12:57.123 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.005043Z General, W: ConfigModel: NativeLanguageCode: he_IL CountryCode: IL
2021-11-16 09:12:57.155 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Sequence [seqIdentity] initialized successfully
2021-11-16 09:12:57.190 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [userInfoTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.203 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [configTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.282 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [groupInfoTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.290 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [memberPermissionOverrideTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.296 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [groupMemberInfoTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.308 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [userDetailsTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.403 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [feedTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.411 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [globalConfigurationTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.417 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [reactionsTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.434 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [settingsTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.439 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [pendingTransfersTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.456 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [groupTopicTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.466 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: Table named [resourcesTable] was initialized successfully (No added new columns)
2021-11-16 09:12:57.466 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: SQFENTITIY: The database is ready for use
2021-11-16 09:12:57.504 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.386166Z General, W: ConfigModel persist loaded, language code: he
2021-11-16 09:12:57.553 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.435633Z General, I: UserModel persist loaded pesrist=
2021-11-16 09:12:57.671 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.553501Z General, D: Groups persist loaded with 2 groups
2021-11-16 09:12:57.755 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.636823Z General, D: GroupsModel: perist loaded with 1
2021-11-16 09:12:57.812 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.694083Z General, I: FeedsModel: Loading from database took 54msec for 0 feeds
2021-11-16 09:12:57.820 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:57.702363Z General, I: FeedsModel: Creation of feeds dictionary took 0msec for 0 feeds
2021-11-16 09:12:58.158 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.040209Z General, D: Global configuration loaded
2021-11-16 09:12:58.179 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.061697Z Localization, D: LocalizationModel:: LoadDatabase
2021-11-16 09:12:58.295 17561-17717/com.twtech.twelveqa E/sqlite3_android: ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2021-11-16 09:12:58.365 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.247065Z General, D: LocalizationService: isRtl=true (twoLettersLanguageCode=he)
2021-11-16 09:12:58.365 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.247811Z Localization, D: LocalizationModel:: languageCode is he, using he
2021-11-16 09:12:58.617 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.498900Z Localization, I: LocalizationModel loaded 1595 entries for language he (took 324ms)
2021-11-16 09:12:58.669 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.551310Z General, I: SettingsModel persist loaded
2021-11-16 09:12:58.696 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.578037Z General, D: ResourcesModel: persist loaded
2021-11-16 09:12:58.728 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.610476Z Network, I: Connection: openConnection, Atmpts=0, Disc=true, CommState=None, InterConnectionPeriodInSec=10
2021-11-16 09:12:58.731 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.612992Z General, I: Network: url:wss://api-qa.megatok.com/WebSocketFEChannel
2021-11-16 09:12:58.767 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.649321Z Network, I: openConnection => Channel not null
2021-11-16 09:12:58.770 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.652101Z Network, I: Real Network up!
2021-11-16 09:12:58.779 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.661702Z AudioSequencer, I: registerQueue QueueContext.Chat-0
2021-11-16 09:12:58.848 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.729843Z General, I: handlePendingFeeds called with priority groupId: null
2021-11-16 09:12:58.855 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.737599Z General, I: AnalyticsControllerFirebase: initialized
2021-11-16 09:12:58.864 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.746750Z ApplicationFlow, I: Load times:
        Services Init: 38ms,
        Widgets Flutter Binding: 39ms
        Cloud Messaging Init: 67ms, 
        Local Notifications Init: 187ms, 
        Models+Auth+Time Init: 694ms, 
        Config Model Init: 797ms, 
        Initial Models: 2606sw, 
        Open Connection: 2680ms, 
        Models Init: 2712ms, 
        Auth Start: 2772ms, 
        firebaseAppConfigureDoneSw: 2766ms, 
        Late Models LoadD: 2774ms, 
    
2021-11-16 09:12:58.873 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.755779Z General, I: Maintenance: Last time running was 2021-11-16 07:09:39.965Z, Minimal time between maintenance activity is 1440 minutes.
2021-11-16 09:12:58.874 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.756356Z General, I: Maintenance: Not running maintenance due to lastMaintenanceTime: 2021-11-16 07:09:39.965Z
2021-11-16 09:12:58.877 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.759534Z General, I: _appUILaunch started
2021-11-16 09:12:58.890 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.772003Z ApplicationFlow, I: Init done
2021-11-16 09:12:58.896 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.778414Z Network, I: Connection: onConnectivityChanged(ConnectivityResult.wifi), Disc=false, CommState=None, Atmpts=1, Disc=false, CommState=None, InterConnectionPeriodInSec=10
2021-11-16 09:12:58.897 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:58.779411Z Network, I: Connection: checkReconnection with Atmpts=1 => reset to 0, Disc=false, CommState=None
2021-11-16 09:12:59.315 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:12:59.197710Z General, I: build main widget started
2021-11-16 09:13:01.045 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:13:00.926909Z General, D: main: BlocBuilder got state event: Uninitialized()
2021-11-16 09:13:02.569 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:13:02.451592Z General, W: Main got Initial DeepLink at startup: null
2021-11-16 09:13:02.657 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: 2021-11-16 07:13:02.539691Z General, W: Main: installReferrer: ReferrerDetails { installReferrer: utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic, referrerClickTimestampSeconds: 0, installBeginTimestampSeconds: 0, googlePlayInstantParam: false }
2021-11-16 09:13:02.662 17561-17706/com.twtech.twelveqa I/flutter: Link is utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic, appUriScheme is tokcastqa, secondaryAppUriScheme is megatokqa
```

Comment: "Short issue description" - why not submit this to audio_service's issue tracker?

Comment: Hi @RyanHeise, I'm working on an example project which reproduces this issue. As soon as I have one, I will submit. If you have any ideas that might save me that effort, please share them...

Comment: Putting in effort is the preferred option.

Comment: Github issue opened, along with the relevant minimal reproduction project (https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/875)